# Postmessage from a tab to another tab

Tags: javascript

I want to send data from a website to another website if it needs chrome extension or not for example i have opened `https://a.com` in a tab in chrome and in another tab `https://b.com` so in here i want send data from `https://b.com` to `https://a.com` with javascript

Code example:

`https://a.com`:

`$(window).on('message',(e)=> { console.log(e.data); })`,

`https://b.com`:

`$.postMessage("this is a message","https://a.com");`

Result in `https://a.com`: `undefined`

Comment: What is `$`? What do you get when you log the complete `e` object?

Comment: To get message on a.com, use `window.addEventListener("message", callback, false)`

Comment: i am using Jquery